# AppleScript - How to open an application when the instance is closed?

Tags: automation, applescript

**Here is the scenario:**

I opened the application and closed the instance with (cmd + w) but did not quit the application. So there is still that dot under that app icon in my dock. Now when I run the below script, the application opens but doesn't come to front.

```
tell application "MyApplication" to activate
```

The scripts works perfectly fine when the application is quit or when it is in hidden state (using cmd + h).

How do I open the application and bring it to front when the instance is closed but is not quit? I want the script to be working for all the three cases (should open it if it is closed and bring it to front):

- Application which is quit and is not running
- Application which is in hidden state (hidden using cmd + h)
- Application whose instance is closed (using cmd + w) but is not quit

Comment: What's the name of the application?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
tell application "MyApplication"
    if it is not running then launch
    set frontmost to true
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: This is the error I got - `Can’t set frontmost to true." number -10006 from frontmost`

Comment: I was assuming that the application has an AppleScript dictionary

Comment: The application doesn't support AppleScript dictionary. Do I still have some way to do it?